# The Lambert-W function?

Tags: lambert-w

I am trying to use the Lambert-W function to solve the following equation for $x$.

$$ \frac{a}{b} \ln x-x+ c =0 $$

My first step is to rewrite $x$ as $e^{\ln x}$.

$$ \frac a b \ln x - e^{ln x} + c =0$$

I then multiply by $b$ and divide by $a$.

$$ \ln x - \frac b a e^{\ln x} + \frac b a c =0 $$

I have read about the Lambert-W function but am unsure of how to progress!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write your equation as
$$ \ln(x) - \frac{bx}{a} = - \frac{bc}{a} $$
take the  exponential of both sides:
$$ x e^{-bx/a} = e^{-bc/a}$$
and multiply by $-b/a$.  With $u = -bx/a$ we have
$$ u e^u = -\frac{b}{a} e^{-bc/a} $$
Thus $u = W\left(-\frac{b}{a} e^{-bc/a}\right)$, and
$$ x = -\frac{a}{b} W\left(-\frac{b}{a} e^{-bc/a}\right) $$

Comment: When everything is complex numbers. Is there a way to obtain a series representation of the value of W at that point,  is it possible to obtain where is the range of W at that point? I am particularly interesting in knowing if the solutions of the initial equation could be near the real axis

Comment: There are series representations of $W$.  For example, $$W(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-k)^{k-1} z^k}{k!}$$ for $|z| < 1/e$.